# Can't have my node app connect to kafka with separate docker compose file

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, apache-kafka, docker-compose

So where is the setup. 2 compose files, soon to be 4. Everything cannot live in the same compose file because it's spread between projects. So what is blowing my mind out of the water is that if I put a basic ngnix server in my kafka docker-compose, I can connect my node app to it just fine... But I can't connect to kafka... If I run my node app outside docker I can connect to kafka just fine... Not sure why I can't connect to kafka.

```
# Micro Services that connect to kafka
version: '3.5'
services:
  grouping:
    build:
      dockerfile: grouping.docker
      context: .
    container_name: grouping
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - notifications-network
  sending:
    build:
      dockerfile: sending.docker
      context: .
    container_name: sending
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - notifications-network
    depends_on:
      - grouping
networks:
  kafka-network:
    external: true
  notifications-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: notifications-network

# Kafka 
version: '3.5'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper"
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - notifications-network
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  kafka:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-kafka"
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - notifications-network
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  web:
    image: nginx
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - "1337:80"
    networks:
      - kafka-network
networks:
  kafka-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: kafka-network
  notifications-network:
    external: true
```

Using `kafka-node` with `config` and I connect like this

```
const kafkaConfig = config.get('kafka');
const kafkaClient = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: kafkaConfig.host});
const consumer = bluebird.promisifyAll(new kafka.Consumer(kafkaClient, [{topic: kafkaConfig.topic}], {autoCommit: false}), {multiArgs: true});
```

I've tried:

```
kafkaConfig.host = 'kafka:9092'
kafkaConfig.host = 'http://kafka:9092'
kafkaConfig.host = 'kafka'
kafkaConfig.host = 'http://kafka'
```

What am I missing? It has to be something simple right?

Docker network ls shows:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                    DRIVER              SCOPE
ee3aceffe54b        bridge                  bridge              local
b05926fff0ed        host                    host                local
18c96f1f6d2d        kafka-network           bridge              local
391880718a8b        none                    null                local
19e81dea1d65        notifications-network   bridge              local
```

Using request, I can connect to the grouping, sending, and web services from the grouping or sending service.

```
const request = require('request');
request.get('http://sending:8081', (err, res) => logger.info('Got from sending:', err, res && res.body));

request.get('http://grouping:8080', (err, res) => logger.info('Got from grouping:', err, res && res.body));

request.get('http://web', (err, res) => logger.info('Got from kafka web:', err, res && res.body));

// Returns a peer reset connection error, which is different from the not found error.
request.get('http://kafka:9092', (err, res) => logger.info('Got from kafka web:', err, res && res.body));
```

**Just an update:**
So the web service is on the kafka-network, my other services can connect to it and they can even try to send a connection to kafka, but kafka doesn't have a webservice and resets the peer. So they can sorta talk with kafka, but kafka isn't working how it's suppose to. I also receive a `Broker not available` error when my kafka client tries to connect inside the docker container.

Comment: To troubleshoot I'd start by getting inside one of the containers and check if I can communicate with the other containers, using tools like `ping` or `telnet` or even `nc`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, that's what I did with the web service. So the web service is on the kafka-network, my other services can connect to it and they can even try to send a connection to kafka, but kafka doesn't have a webservice and resets the peer. So they can sorta talk with kafka, but kafka isn't working how its suppose to.

Comment: So it actually works. I just had my config file in the docker ignore... Rip...

Answer (score 0):

I'm even sure if this is a valid answer, but in a nutshell, what's above works just fine with you use kafka:9092 as the host name. I had my dockerignore file ignoring my local.json, so the file I was editing never was copied over...

**Update:**
Config was just part of the answer, the other part of the environment variables for kafka.

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

we need to have this not be `localhost:9092`, but as `kafka:9092`

apparently I was already doing this with zookeeper but never realized it.

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to connet from both a process in your compose network and from outside you need to advertise two listeners one internally PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092 like in the previous answer and one for the external use:  EXTERNAL://localhost:9093

Accessing Kafka with internal and external clients
In order to use internal and external clients to access Kafka brokers you need to configure one listener for each kind of clients.

To do so, add the following environment variables to your docker-compose:

```
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
```

this is from the bitnami image: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka but the confluent kafka image should work the same